# How to install mongoDB and check the version

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new in mongoDB and I installed the mongodb in window 32 bit using:-

**C:>npm install -g mongo**

And It installed successfully But When I used

c:>mongo -v

This is giving Error:-

**'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

I set the environment variable path is:-

C:\mongodb;

But it is not working. Same error happens.

Answer (score 3):

You've only installed the Nodejs module to interact with mongodb.

Install instructions here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/

Once you've installed `mongo -v` should work.

Comment: means C:>npm install -g mongo
 This command which package installed is not useful

Comment: It is useful to allow nodejs work with mongoldb. You need it, it's just a connector though.

Comment: means now again I have to install mongoDB using some instruction

Comment: @shahzadahmed Yes, RTFM maybe? SO is not about holding your hand to do a basic installation. **phelpsiv** already wasted his time to give a doc link you could find in 5s.

Answer (score 1):

You can check mongodb version using `db.version()` if you have installed mongodb.

Comment: Where I have to use this function actually i am fresher in MongoDB

Comment: Are you able to access mongodb shell? in shell just run this method `db.version()`